# growing up with linux scripting and online resource to learn it

Tags: linux, shell-script, career

Is learning Linux shell scripting good for developing own career?I use linux and very much interested in scripting. Where should I start from?

Comment: Regarding the second question, you could try `info bash`?

Comment: Please read the help on types of Q's to ask here, this isn't a good fit for the types of Q's allowed. http://unix.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'$ info bash' should be your first stop. It's comprehensive, has plenty of examples & is from the source (GNU) itself. Learning shell programming is a good choice & will be of great help in your career.